# Detect full-screen width & height in node webkit

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit, nw.js

I'm able to get the node webkit app to load full screen with this in my html's javascript:

```
"use strict";

const gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
win.enterFullscreen();
```

So after reading https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Screen , I tried this:

```
"use strict";

const gui = require('nw.gui');
var win = gui.Window.get();
var screen = gui.Screen.Init();

var onDisplayBoundsChanged = function(screen) {
  alert("hey");
}

gui.Screen.on('displayBoundsChanged', onDisplayBoundsChanged);

// win.enterFullscreen();
win.maximize();

window.client = new GameClient(screen);
```

I never see the alert.
Ideally I want to delay

```
window.client = new GameClient(screen);
```

until after the application fullscreens and has a new, full screen bounds I can use.

How do I detect full-screen and get the width & height?

Comment: Have you tried `window.screen.height` and `window.screen.width`

Comment: the app starts not full screen, so those values will be smaller than after full screening. How do I get the correct values after full-screening?

Comment: No `window.screen.height` gives the height of the device screen, not the browser window, check it on console

Comment: window.screen.height is undefined

Comment: is this a browser app ??

Comment: It's HTML, yes.

Comment: Friend just inspect your browser goto console paste this `window.screen.width` and press enter to see your device width

Comment: Ohh you r trying this on serve-side code thats why its not working, it will only work in client side code(on browser)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153702/discussion-between-quantumpotato-and-ananthakrishnan-baji).

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood what gui.Screen.Init() was returning.

Change `var screen` to

`var screen = gui.Screen.Init().screens[0];`

then

```
    generateCanvas(screen) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    Thing.prototype.scale = 1;

    // let bounds = screen.bounds;
    let sw = screen.bounds.width;
    let sh = screen.bounds.height;
```